# How to know an attribute is delegated or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country

  delegate :name, to: :country, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  def greet
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

person = Person.first
person.country_name #=> print country name
```

do you guys know whether there is one method:

```rb
person.delegated?(:country_name) # => true
person.delegated?(:greet) # => false
person.delegated?(:name) # => false -------> name is one attribute of person
```

or how to implement the method?

Comment: Why do you want to know? What ist the use case?

Comment: ^^ This. Your question feels like a potential XY problem to me. I'm struggling to see why your code would need to know this information. (Or, is it purely an academic question? Are you just trying to see if the above challenge is *possible*?)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, You can check if the particular column exists in the table by ```person.class.column_names.include?("name")```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following as an initializer:

```ruby
class Module
  def delegated_methods
    @delegated_methods ||= {}
  end

  alias_method :old_delegate, :delegate
  def delegate(*methods, **opts)
    old_delegate(*methods, **opts)

    methods.each do |method|
      delegated_methods[method.to_s] = opts
    end
  end
end
```

You would then be able to call `.delegated_methods` on the `Person` class:

```ruby
Person.delegated_methods
#=> {"name"=>{:to=>:country, :prefix=>true, :allow_nil=>true}}

person = Person.new
person.class.delegated_methods
#=> {"name"=>{:to=>:country, :prefix=>true, :allow_nil=>true}}

Person.delegated_methods.keys
#=> ["name"]

Person.delegated_methods.key?("name")
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Get inspiration from the above answer, so I add the logic in the `ApplicationRecord` model. All models extend from `ApplicationRecord`.

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  class << self
    def delegated_methods
      @delegated_methods ||= {}.with_indifferent_access
    end

    alias old_delegate delegate

    def delegate(*methods, **opts)
      old_delegate(*methods, **opts)

      opts.symbolize_keys!

      method_prefix = \
        if opts[:prefix]
          "#{opts[:prefix] == true ? opts[:to] : opts[:prefix]}_"
        else
          ''
        end
      methods.each do |method|
        method_name = opts[:prefix] ? "#{method_prefix}#{method}" : method
        delegated_methods[method_name] = opts
      end
    end

    def delegated?(method)
      delegated_methods.key?(method)
    end
  end
end
```

here is `post.rb` model which extends `ApplicationRecord`

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  has_one :country, through: :person
  delegate :job, to: :person, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  delegate :name, to: :country, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

for now we can use it:

```rb
2.7.1 (main):0 > Post.delegated_methods
=> {"person_job"=>{"to"=>:person, "prefix"=>true, "allow_nil"=>true}, "country_name"=>{"to"=>:country, "prefix"=>true, "allow_nil"=>true}}
2.7.1 (main):0 > Post.delegated?(:country_name)
=> true
2.7.1 (main):0 > Post.delegated?(:person_job)
=> true
2.7.1 (main):0 > Post.delegated?('person_job')
=> true
2.7.1 (main):0 > Post.delegated?('country_name')
=> true
```